# Opencart 2.1 Wrong API Key Error

Tags: api, opencart, opencart2.x

I have a opencart 2.1 website and I can't change order details. I see this error in orders page:(Wrong API Key!)
[image: order page]
I gave all permission to my account. I added a API, I added my ip to this API like this:
[image: api page]

I searched but I didn't found an answer. I tried this https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=163403 but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=153201

Comment: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=28614

Comment: @TejasMehta Thanks for advice. I searched in this topic I saw a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by this:
I deleted this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I don't know how to effect my system but it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps

1. Log in to your admin panel.
2. Go to System > User Group
3. Now edit Administrator or any other user you are using.
4. Now in "Access Permission" and "Modify Permission" , click on select all button and save.
5. Now you will be able to modify orders.

Hope it helps.